# Apply ifelse logic to all columns with shared prefix in R

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement

```
a<-c("a_1", "a_2", "a_3", "a_4", "b_5", "b", "b_9", "c", "c1", "c_1")
x<-c(0,0,0,1,"a",5,8,0,0,9)
y<-c(0,0,1,0,"b",5,8,0,0,9)
z<-c(0,0,0,0,"c",5,8,0,0,9)
y.df<-as.data.frame(t(data.frame(x,y,z)))
colnames(y.df)<-a
y.df$a_1<-as.numeric(y.df$a_1)
y.df$a_2<-as.numeric(y.df$a_2)
y.df$a_3<-as.numeric(y.df$a_3)
y.df$a_4<-as.numeric(y.df$a_4)
y.df
  a_1 a_2 a_3 a_4 b_5 b b_9 c c1 c_1  
   0   0   0   1  50  5   8 0  0   9   
   0   0   1   0  50  5   8 0  0   9   
   0   0   0   0  50  5   8 0  0   9
```

I have a data.frame akin to the sample data above where I have a series of columns that all share the same suffix (except in the actual data, there are many more columns -hence the need for this question). 
I would like a way to apply the same `ifelse` clause to all the columns that share a prefix without having to explicitly write out the name of each column (because in my real data i have 40+ columns). So in this example, I would like a new column with values of `PASS` or `FAIL` based on an `ifelse` logic that makes use of all the columns with the same prefix. Here is how I would handle it if the number of columns is limited like in my example above:

```
y.df$test<-ifelse(y.df$a_1 == 0 & y.df$a_2 == 0 & y.df$a_3 == 0 & y.df$a_4 == 0, "FAIL", "PASS")
y.df
  a_1 a_2 a_3 a_4 b_5 b b_9 c c1 c_1 test
   0   0   0   1  50  5   8 0  0   9 PASS
   0   0   1   0  50  5   8 0  0   9 PASS
   0   0   0   0  50  5   8 0  0   9 FAIL
```

I tried the following but to no avail:

```
ifelse("a_" %in% colnames(y.df) == 0, "PASS", "FAIL")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do

```
y.df$test <- ifelse(rowSums(y.df[, grepl("a_*", names(y.df))]) == 0, "PASS", "FAIL")
```

Credit to @Gregor.

Comment: Thank you, but i jsut realized this does not work on my actual data bc in my actual data some of the columns are non numeric (all the ones that do not start with a_ for example, i have revised my question.)

Comment: I remove the columns that does not have the prefix a_, so it wouldn't matter if the other columns are non-numeric. So, i think this solution would work even if some of those are non-numeric. Right?

Comment: unfortunately thats not the case but no worries, based on your solution I was able to get the following: `ifelse(rowSums(apply(y.df[, grepl("a_*", names(y.df))], 2, as.numeric))== 0, "PASS", "FAIL")`

Comment: Looks like your problem was that some of the `a_` columns are not numeric. I would suggest cleaning your data by converting them to numeric in your data frame, then running this code as-is.

Comment: Yeah it does appear that you are correct. However, for whatever reason, my actual dataset is indeed numeric for those analogous columns and my solution works in that case. Either way i accepted this as the solution based on whats posted. Thanks